# Android : RecyclerView add bottom ProgressBar

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to add a ProgressBar at the bottom of my RecyclerView but the problem is detecting the bottom of the RecyclerView.

My **getItemViewType** always return 1, because list.get(position) is always not null even when I scroll to the bottom of the RecyclerView, here's my code

```
 @Override
 public int getItemViewType(int position) {
  return list.get(position) != null ? 1 : 0;
 }
```

Can any body point the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouls override [getItemCount](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#getItemCount()) method with

```
return list.size() + 1;
```

and replace

```
return list.get(position) != null ? 1 : 0;
```

with

```
return (list.size() == position) ? 1 : 0;
```

then you should check viewType (0 is your cell and 1 is loading one) in *onCreateViewHolder* method and use proper ViewHolder (refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type) for example).

Also there is a better way to have boolean value to track whether additional data is available to prevent showing loading cell if the last page of data was already uploaded:

```
@Override
int getItemCount () {
    return list.size() + moreDataAvailable ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Comment: it didn't work it show me this exception : java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 26, size is 26

Comment: I already did that, it works fine but I think it should be "return (list.size() == position) ? 0 : 1;", any way thanks I coudn't make it without your help.

Comment: Also moving 0 and 1 to constants would be a great idea :) Have a nice coding!

Comment: Yeah sure, sorry I didn't read this "you should check viewType (0 is your cell and 1 is loading one)", thanks again.